# Generic part of tour page needs to be corrected

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I join a site on Stack Exchange network, the first thing I do is to check the tour page - specifically the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" paragraph which lists what questions are and are not allowed on the particular sub-site.

That paragraph on Puzzling's tour unfortunately diverges dramatically the way this site is used. It says it is for `Specific questions about the creation and solving of puzzles`, but every single question that I've seen on "Newest Questions" and SE-wide "Most Popular" was just a straight-up puzzle with answers being straight-up solutions. No analysis, no discussion on the craft.

It ought to be fixed.

This thread is for brainstorming a sleek, clean and informative replacement.

Comment: This simply isn't true, though. We are _definitely_ a site where questions on puzzle crafting are completely okay. It's not _just_ challenge questions.

Comment: @Emrakul Oh, that's good to know.

Comment: However, it would make more sense to say it is about 'Solving puzzles, and specific questions about the creation of puzzles'. Currently, you could read it as questions about (the creation and solving) of puzzles. It is far more about 'solving' then 'questions about solving'. But that's nitpicking.

Answer (score -3):

My top-of-the-head suggestion:

- Puzzles you made yourself.
- Obscure puzzles made by other people that have not been posted yet.